# How to include recipients when copying an email from (Firefox88 browser, Windows7) Outlook to a Text Editor

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, notepad++

1. I open an email in Outlook;
2. I do mouse-right-click "Select All" and CTRL+C (the recipients field is not highlighted);
3. I go to a new document in a text editor (such as Notepad++ or Word);
4. I do: CTRL+V;
5. The text of the email is pasted together with most of the header information;
6. But the recipients information (e.g. To:xxxxxx@xxxxxx CC:yyy@yyyyyy ) is not pasted.

I cannot even select and copy just the recipient information from the email in Outlook.

Is there a simple solution for this please?

Comment: A simple workaround is to click Reply or Reply All or Forward. The message will be displayed with the headers included in the body. Copy from the "From" down to the end of the message.

Comment: @Reddy Lutonadio That's perfect, thankyou!

Comment: Should I write it as an answer?

Comment: @Reddy Lutonadio Yes please (if you wish to)!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can include the headers' fields by clicking Reply or Reply All or Forward. The message will be displayed with the headers included in the body. Copy from the "From:" down to the end of the message.

Comment: Good sharing. Your suggestion is very useful!